# Delete requests with Phils RESTserver is wrong?

Tags: codeigniter, rest

I am struggling with delete requests using Codeigniter and Phils RESTserver.

As I understand a delete request is normally sent in the URL (the ID) but now I am forced to
send it as an "attachment", like a POST request and that does not work with my RestClient (appcelerator).

Is this a bug? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you provide some more details please? Maybe show some code of your client or your controller where you want to handle the delete request.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just send a post request and then handle it as if you're deleting something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the bug is as you haven't really said what is happening.

```
 but now I am forced to send it as an "attachment"
```

Why are you being forced? Is there an error? Did you debug the value and find that nothing was being sent? What are you talking about?! :)

You can do this:

**DELETE: /foo/bar/45**

```
class Foo extends REST_Controller {
    public function bar_delete($id) {}
}
```

If that doesn't work then file a bug report ;-)